# How to find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ = {$\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}$}. Also how about working out the subgroups for a much larger number e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Comment: By Lagrange, the order of each subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4$ is a factor of $4$. There aren't many factors of $4$.

Comment: You may want to use Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: It says in the answers all the subgroups are: $\mathbb{Z}_4$, $\bar{0}$ and  ($\bar{0}$,$\bar{2}$) so shouldnt $\bar{1}$ be a subgroup too?

Comment: "shouldnt 1 be a subgroup too?" Do you think $1$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z_4$?

Comment: @NoteBook Does it really say that in the "answers"? The subgroups are $\Bbb Z_4$, $\{\overline 0\}$ and $\{\overline 0,\overline 2\}$.

Comment: Yes @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Does the question ask for all the *proper* subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/4$?

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $(i)$ $\Bbb Z _m$ is a cyclic group of order m .

$(ii)$ There is  a well-known result : If $G$ is a cyclic group of finite order (say, $n$), then for each positive integer $d$ so that $d|n$, $\exists$a unique subgroup of $G$ of order $d$.  (In fact, you can try to prove this delicate, yet not-so-difficult result).

$(iii)$ Combining $(i)$ and $(ii)$ , find all possible orders of subgroups of $G$.

$(iv)$ Any subgroup of a Cyclic group is Cyclic.

$(v)$ In any finite cyclic group there exists an element with order equal to the order of the group.

Best Of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no exact formula. You can find these subgroups by trial and error and some known theorems which help to find orders, like Lagrange's theorem, Cauchy's theorem and Sylow theorems. 
Try to combine elements and see what you get.